# Contract event - transactionIndex and logIndex

Tags: web3js, events

I need to monitor contract events and perform off-chain processing. How do I uniquely identify a contract event? Can I use a combination of these fields?
- transactionHash
- transactionIndex
- logIndex

I supposed I cannot use transactionHash alone because 1 transaction may emit multiple events. IMO, the documentation https://github.com/ethereum/wiki/wiki/JavaScript-API#contract-events doesn't describe the fields transactionIndex and logIndex well.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

If two events are logged in one transaction, `transactionIndex` is going to be the same.

Using `transactionHash` and `logIndex` should enable you to identify unique event logs.

Comment: Thanks. Can you also explain the meaning of these 2 fields transactionIndex and logIndex?

Comment: The `transactionIndex` is the index of the transaction in the block. The `logIndex` is the index of the log in the block logs

Comment: Came here looking to verify that `\`${transactionhash}-${logIndex}\`` is unique to each log, thanks for nailing it down!

Answer (score 4):

You can only uniquely identify an event within the context of a block. As per https://github.com/ethereum/wiki/wiki/JSON-RPC#eth_getfilterchanges, the logIndex refers to position within a block, so you'll probably have to go with blockHash+txHash+logIndex combo. If not, a reorg can happen, and the same combination of txHash+logIndex can refer to a different event.